# How to apply cUrl get data in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I would like to ask about applying cUrl on CodeIgniter.
 Where should I put the cURL coding, is it in view or controller?

Comment: put the logic in the controller and process accordingly, then put the necessary output into view

Comment: How about if I applied cURL on codeigniter and I want to filter the cURL output?

Comment: it depends, you'd certainly want your controller to filter those data that you'd only want, the view just outputs it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller would be fine, for example

```
`function index()
{
    // Get cURL resource
    $curl = curl_init();
    // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost/ci_paginationv2-
        master/index.php/API/API_airtime_share',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
    ));
    // Send the request & save response to $resp
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    // Close request to clear up some resources
    curl_close($curl);

    echo $resp;

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be putting your logic in the controller itself as per the Code Igniter Conventions and then process the response there itself (if needed) and then render the view for the same (if the data needs to be viewed). Please comment if something is unclear.

[Click Here to see more on this](http://www.formget.com/curl-library-codeigniter/)

Comment: Please approve this if it helped you.